# Jquery function doesn't load - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to install this datetimepicker for bootstrap:
https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/wiki/Installation

I've got this in the header of my document:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And this in the footer:

```
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

And here is the code using the picker:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' >
                        <input type='text' name="picker" class="form-control" id='datetimepicker'/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
```

The problem is that .datetimepicker is an "unresolved function". Why?

Edit:

The IDE (PHPStorm) says that it's unresolved function. And actually running it in Chrome confirms:

```
    bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    myfile.php:42 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Must choose at least one picker
```

Edit2: I updated the header/footer.
Header:

Footer:

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-rowlink.js"></script>
<script src="/js/myscripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Now IDE recognizes datetimepicker() as a function, but still the same problem in Chrome! (see above)

Comment: Can you show me the full source code? I think your error is not happen in the browser.

Comment: check with firebug to see if the js files are correctly loaded

Comment: The full source code is a little "sensitive", but I'll try to remove sensitive stuff and post source later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including only jQuery in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

and these in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

The author uses jQuery 2.1.1 so his plugin may be reliant on that version.

**EDIT**

I cannot get it to work, either.  However, there are a few Issues created on its Github page since Moment.js has been updated to version 2.8.4.  Try [Smalot's Bootstrap Datepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).  It's also well maintained and it works for me.

Comment: I tried adding jquery 2.1.1 to the header and moving the rest to footer. See edit2 of my post. Still not working!

Comment: @JamesB See my edit. It may be to the plugin not playing nicely with momentjs (I'm sure it's temporary as the github page lists recent changes) and I don't know when it will be fixed. I recommended a different datepicker that's good.

Comment: The one you linked to is perfect! Picking time was important for me, and the time picking looks brilliant. Thanks!

I'm not going troubleshoot anymore, and just assume you are right that it's actually a problem with moment or the script itself. I implemented a different timepicker before with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling the `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();` too early, you should organize your code like this :

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
                });
</script>
```

Comment: this is actually issue your would be as similar issue I faced earlier.

Comment: I tried to add it to the end, but it didn't help :(

Comment: the problem is not in the call to `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();` but in the plugin declaration, try using the non-minified version of bootstrap-datetimepicker.js and update (again) your question

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function on document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Passing a function directly to the jQuery function (i.e. `$(function() {...})`) is a shorthand for a document ready handler, so the code they have already does this.

Answer (score 0):

check the example from the authors [site](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

you are using it wrong, you need to reference the enclosing div and not your input element.

your HTML should look like this:

```html
              <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' >
                        <input type='text' name="picker" class="form-control"/>
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```